# Upload the PySpark dataframe to bigquery as a dataproc job

Tags: pyspark, google-bigquery, jar, google-cloud-dataproc, spark-bigquery-connector

I'm trying to submit a PySpark job on Dataproc cluster. My Pyspark job is uploading a dataframe to bigquery.
When I do it using submit job on the cluster, I face an error, the job fails. But, when I provide this jar :
"gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar", in the jar file parameter in submit job, the job executes successfully.

What I wanted is to find a way to avoid providing this jar during run-time and just run the job by giving the location of .py file alone. How can I do it? Is it somehow possible to specify this jar within the .py file itself?

I used the below approach to provide the jar in the .py file itself but it doesn't seem to work.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('yarn')\
.config('spark.jars', 'gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar') \
.appName('df-to-bq-sample').enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

Can anyone suggest a way to do it, and I do not want to use CLI for this.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you please share the log from the run of the above log?

Comment: Also, what is the problem of adding additional CLI flag?

Comment: @DavidRabinowitz, the reason i dont want to add the jar as an additional parameter at run time is becoz, I will be orchestrating the job in Cloud Composer(Airflow). 
So, my Airflow DAG tasks would be ,
             create dataproc cluster >> Run the pyspark job >> delete cluster.
Here, my DAG fails during the second task, that is while running the pyspark job as I can't give the jar in between while the DAG is running.

Comment: Ok, so you can add the connector to the cluster as described below

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the mentioned is a must when reading and writing to BigQuery. If you don't want to add it to the job submission, you can add the BigQuery connector jar on cluster creation using the [connectors init action](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/initialization-actions/tree/master/connectors) like this:

```
REGION=<region>
CLUSTER_NAME=<cluster_name>
gcloud dataproc clusters create ${CLUSTER_NAME} \
    --region ${REGION} \
    --initialization-actions gs://goog-dataproc-initialization-actions-${REGION}/connectors/connectors.sh \
    --metadata spark-bigquery-connector-version=0.24.2
```